# Update/ Retrieve /Inserting date field

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am having difficulties while updating a date field into the Database. The field type in the DB is Date/Time.

Now, I am trying to update the field name "R_Date".

Currently, I am using the SQL Expression in my jsp"
`UPDATE request SET request_date ='"+Request_Date+"'";` , But it is not accepting.

In the select statement I am using a normal select, I tried to use to_char or to_date, but it is not accepting the format of "DD-MMM-YYYY"

So, can you please help me to retrive/Update/Insert date field in the format of "DD-MMM-YYYY" the date field?

Comment: is there any reason to not use PreparedSteatements ?

Comment: Writing JDBC code in JSP and having problems with it doesn't make it a JSP problem. So I removed the JSP tag.

Answer (score 2):

The normal practice to store a timestamp in the DB (thus, `java.util.Date` in Java side and `java.sql.Timestamp` in JDBC side) is to use [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29).

```
Date requestDate = getItSomehow();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(requestDate.getTime());
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE request SET request_date = ?");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
```

The normal practice to obtain a timestamp from the DB is to use [`ResultSet#getTimestamp()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int%29).

```
Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp("request_date");
Date requestDate = timestamp; // You can just upcast.
```

To convert between `java.util.Date` and `java.lang.String` you normally use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
// Convert from String to Date.
String requestDateAsString = "09-Aug-2010";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date requestDate = sdf.parse(requestDateAsString);

// Convert from Date to String.
String anotherDateAsString = sdf.format(someDate);
```

#### See also:

- [PreparedStatement tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) (!!!)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use MON instead of MMM.

Have you tried something like:

```
UPDATE request
SET request_date = to_date('" + Request_Date + "', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Hope you realize that as your statement stands (if it worked), it would update every row in the request table (not sure if that's your intention or not but I thought I'd point it out).

Comment: Yes, it may be that the error is not what you think it is. We can't help without the appropriate information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what date format you are trying to insert, and try using to_date method with appropriate format.

Following is referenced from : http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html

Oracle's default format for DATE is "DD-MON-YY".
If you want to retrieve date in particular format you need to use :

```
    TO_CHAR(<date>, '<format>')
```

Similarly if you need to insert/update date with input of date other than in standard format, you need to use :

```
TO_DATE(<string>, '<format>')
```

where the `<format>` string can be formed from over 40 options. Some of the more popular ones include:

```
    MM  Numeric month (e.g., 07)
    MON Abbreviated month name (e.g., JUL)
    MONTH   Full month name (e.g., JULY)
    DD  Day of month (e.g., 24)
    DY  Abbreviated name of day (e.g., FRI)
    YYYY    4-digit year (e.g., 1998)
    YY  Last 2 digits of the year (e.g., 98)
    RR  Like YY, but the two digits are ``rounded'' to a year in the range 1950 to 2049. Thus, 06 is considered 2006 instead of 1906
    AM (or PM)  Meridian indicator
    HH  Hour of day (1-12)
    HH24    Hour of day (0-23)
    MI  Minute (0-59)
    SS  Second (0-59)
```